# iOS Parse query with mixed objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, relational-database

I have a chat application working with Parse.com.

In my app users able to like posts. Like button has liked and normal states. So the next time when the user open the app I should show the posts that user liked with liked button state.

Server objects:
1) User
2) Post
3) Like

User object columns:
1. Likes(relation) - all liked posts by the user
2. Posts(relation) - all user posted posts

Post object columns:
1. Users(pointer) - created by user pointer
2. Likes(relation) - all existing likes on the post

Like object columns:
1. User(pointer) - liked by user
2. Post(pointer) - liked post

/**** PROBLEM ****/
Now I'm getting all posts from the "Posts" table, then getting the all liked posts from the "User's Liked posts relation" and if the post from the Posts table exists in the "User's Liked posts relation" I'm changing the Like button state to Liked.

I don't like how I'm doing it as now I'm calling two requests for showing the posts Like button state correct. I'm sure that it's possible to do with single request, but don't know how.

Can someone help me please ???

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to use any data from your User class to deduce what you want. You can simply get the associated Likes data for each Post object in a single query. Then process the Likes information for each one and see if the current user is there to set the Like button state:

```
// Get all the posts
let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

// Include all like objects to for each post as well
postQuery.includeKey("Likes")

// execute the query
postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    // objects are all of the Post objects, and their associated Like objects, too
    // Process data for each post and check the likes info to see if your current 
    // user is there, then set the Like button accordingly
}
```

Comment: includeKey works only for fetching Pointers and not relations.
https://www.parse.com/questions/includekey-not-working-for-many-to-many-relational-data-query-ios